# Option Dimensional Information in Data Warehouse Dim Tables

Tags: sql, ssis, data-warehouse

I am creating a Data Warehouse and have hit a interesting problem...

I have DimQualification and DimUnit tables. A unit is a part of a qualification.

However some units are optional. In stating all available units in the DimUnit table i am puzzled by how best to show the customers choice.

FactAttendance - The attendance on the qualification

Would it be best to put multiple rows in the fact table (qualification and units taken) or is there another option?

Comment: Are you saying FactAttendance is 1 to Many DimQualification is 1 to Many DimUnit ? If so I think you have to have multiple records in Fact Attendance. Or If there is a Max number of Qualification that many columns, I prefer the first.

Comment: Exactly right, so one person can do many qualifications and one qualification is made up of many units.

I thought this would be the case but it is best to check.

Thanks Holmes IV

Comment: How many unit choices are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at a few things now and have decided that there is a way to achieve this without the reduction in speed which multiple rows in the fact table would create.

Instead of having the multiple rows for each unit I am going to create another fact table which holds all the units chosen then from the FactAttendance table we can immediately and efficiently identify the units chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The other option, besides putting multiple rows in the fact table, is to have a single row for each fact in the fact table, and a separate column for each unit.   The column would be a count of the number of that unit associated with that fact.   Something like this:

```
FactID  Unit1Count  Unit2Count  Unit3Count ...
```